gitlab-runner cannot access gitlab-repo
I have a linux  gitlab and runner instance running on the same machine.
The machine is accessible from the web via https, which is protected by cloudflare.
A ufw and swwitch level firewall protect the machine from the web and only accept cloudflare ip ranges.
I configured the gitlab to run with the origin CA certificate provided by cloudflare and can use gitlab just fine. Now when I added the runner and tried a test pipeline, it cannot checkout the repo I'm running on:
Here's the log from the pipeline:
Running with gitlab-runner 17.4.0 (b92ee590)
  on offsite iKYgymMmt, system ID: s_e94e403982b5
Resolving secrets
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:04
Using Docker executor with image alpine:latest ...
Pulling docker image alpine:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:91ef0af61f39ece4d6710e465df5ed6ca12112358344fd51ae6a3b886634148b for alpine:latest with digest alpine@sha256:beefdbd8a1da6d2915566fde36db9db0b524eb737fc57cd1367effd16dc0d06d ...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on runner-ikygymmmt-project-2-concurrent-0 via offsite...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/group/project/.git/
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.example.com/group/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

The runner is configured as follows:
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
log_level = "debug"
connection_max_age = "15m0s"
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "offsite"
  url = "https://gitlab.example.com"
  id = 2
  token = "glrt-token"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-09-30T10:53:10Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0

Any hint, where to look for a fix?
I tried using clone_url with the IP of the server, but with HTTPS this obviously fails:
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
